# Accessing an API (made in the Wolfram Cloud) using a standalone application

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I created an API function that given an integer, would return the factors of that integer.

```
func=APIFunction[{"x"->"Integer"},FactorInteger[#x]&];
api=CloudDeploy[func]
```

This returns a URL which I can now append my query string to and submit for an answer.

```
Hyperlink[First[api]<>"?x=2434500"]
```

Instead of making this function call in Mathematica, I would like to call this function in a standalone application (using LiveCode). When I attempt this, my application requests the info from the URL, but it returns nothing. I believe this may be because there are credentials that I must provide to the Wolfram Cloud so it knows it is me. However, I do not know how to do this. Does anyone have experience making API calls to Wolfram Cloud (without using the EmbedCode[] function)? How do I go about authenticating with Wolfram Cloud? Are there other things that must be done by my application before this would work?

I also tested this by making an API that was Public like so:

```
func=APIFunction[{"x"->"Integer"},FactorInteger[#x]&];
api=CloudDeploy[func,Permissions->"Public"]
```

This also did not work.

Comment: When you access the URL in LiveCode, does `the result` contain any useful diagnostic information?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I also tried to specify the format as "Text" in the event that mattered, but to no avail.

Comment: `CloudDeploy` in V10 front end authenticates using WolframID popup. Don't know about programmatically, isn't it an `Option`?

Comment: Changed the title to make more general. Since I am having the same problem with "Public" as well, I feel like there is something that I missing to make the RESTful API work.

Answer (score 2):

If you've made the API public, you should not need to authenticate. You can validate this by opening the URL in a different browser that does not have an OAuth session with any wolfram sites.  You may be running into XSS issues, which may require that you use CORS or similar.  I'm not familiar with LiveCode, but you might look into how it handles XSS issues.